# Averaging at end of interval

Tags: mysql

I created an SQL view to average the tabled data every 10 minutes:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME((FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`test_data`.`DTS`) / (10 * 60))) * (10 * 60))),
            '%m/%d/%y %H:%i') AS `AVG DTS`,
    AVG(`test_data`.`A`) AS `AVG A`,
    AVG(`test_data`.`B`) AS `AVG B`,
    AVG(`test_data`.`C`) AS `AVG C`
FROM
    `test_data`
WHERE
    (`test_data`.`DTS` BETWEEN '2016-04-22 00:00' AND '2016-05-03 00:00')
GROUP BY `AVG DTS`
```

The table is as follows: (note: time stamps are not sorted on purpose as this may be the way data is placed into the table in our real world)

```
 DTS,A,B,C
"2016-04-22 12:01:00",2,5,8
"2016-04-22 12:02:00",3,6,9
"2016-04-22 12:03:00",4,7,1
"2016-04-22 12:04:00",5,8,2
"2016-04-22 12:05:00",6,9,3
"2016-04-22 12:06:00",7,1,4
"2016-04-22 12:07:00",8,2,5
"2016-04-22 12:08:00",9,3,6
"2016-04-22 12:09:00",1,4,7
"2016-04-22 12:10:00",2,5,8
"2016-04-22 12:11:00",3,6,9
"2016-04-22 12:12:00",4,7,1
"2016-04-22 12:13:00",5,8,2
"2016-04-22 12:14:00",6,9,3
"2016-04-22 12:15:00",7,1,4
"2016-04-22 12:16:00",8,2,5
"2016-04-22 12:17:00",9,3,6
"2016-04-22 12:18:00",1,4,7
"2016-04-22 12:19:00",2,5,8
"2016-04-22 12:20:00",3,6,9
"2016-04-22 12:00:00",1,4,7
"2016-04-22 12:21:00",4,7,1
"2016-04-22 12:22:00",5,8,2
"2016-04-22 12:23:00",6,9,3
"2016-04-22 12:24:00",7,1,4
"2016-04-22 12:25:00",8,2,5
"2016-04-22 12:26:00",9,3,6
```

The output is as follows:

```
"AVG DTS","AVG A","AVG B","AVG C"
"04/22/16 12:00",4.6000,4.9000,5.2000
"04/22/16 12:10",4.7000,5.0000,5.3000
"04/22/16 12:20",6.0000,5.1429,4.2857
```

The `AVG DTS` for 12:00 is an average of the table entries for the appropriate columns from 12:00 to 12:09, `AVG DTS` for 12:10 is an average of the table entries for the appropriate columns from 12:10 to 12:19, etc.

I would like the first output to be `AVG DTS` for 12:10, which would be the average of the table entries for the appropriate columns from 12:01 to 12:10.  The next `AVG DTS` output would be at 12:20 and would be the average of the table entries for the appropriate columns from 12:11 to 12:20.  etc.

Also, if there is a better way to code this please let me know.

Thnx